# Gutenberg extend blocks add new class name

Tags: javascript, block-editor

I'm trying to add an extra class name to all the blocks by extending them. Documentation: [Extending Blocks](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/docs/extensibility/extending-blocks.md)

I'm using `blocks.BlockEdit` to modify the edit component. I want to add a custom class name.

So far I have this

```
const withClass = createHigherOrderComponent( ( BlockListBlock ) => {
    return ( props ) => {
        let wrapperProps = props.wrapperProps;
        wrapperProps = {
            ...wrapperProps,
            className: 'my-custom-class',
        };

        return <BlockListBlock { ...props } wrapperProps={ wrapperProps } />;
    };
}, 'withClass' );
```

It's working by adding the custom class to the wrapper but it is overwriting the default block class. Is it possible to append to the current classes without overriding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do this via the `classnames()` function.

```
import classnames from 'classnames';

const withClass = createHigherOrderComponent( ( BlockListBlock ) => {
    return ( props ) => {
        let wrapperProps = props.wrapperProps;
        wrapperProps = {
            ...wrapperProps,
            className={ classnames( 'my-custom-class', props.className ) }
        };

        return <BlockListBlock { ...props } wrapperProps={ wrapperProps } />;
    };
}, 'withClass' );
```

Comment: You don't _need_ to use `classnames()` to do that, it's just a convenience (and overkill for this situation IMO). You could achieve the same thing with `className={ 'my-custom-class ' + props.className  }` or `className={ \`my-custom-class ${props.className}\` }`.

Comment: Good point Ian. You can do it either way. I guess it's down to personal preference really. I tend to use `classnames` because of my earliest experiences with the WordPress block editor when I thought you did have to do it that way so became a habit!