# How to Add a Container Class to Standard Gutenberg Blocks

Tags: block-editor

I am using ACF fields to create custom Gutenberg Blocks. I am running into an issue however where I need to go in and out of a container div depending on the block. So I cant just add a container div around the_content();

What I'm trying to do is add a class to each of the standard Gutenberg blocks, so I can add the container styles to each of those blocks, making it easier to go in and out of the container div for better content styling.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Related / possible duplicates:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/304145/3898, 
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/308044/3898

Comment: This is what group blocks and block styles/variants are meant to do

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the group block](https://wordpress.org/support/article/group-block/) to act as a container for a core block or any other block...